# Построение матрицы вида через мировые координаты в OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, матрицы, glm, assimp

Я использую библиотеку `assimp` для импорта 3d сцены. С мешами проблем нет. Проблемы с камерой. У меня не получается построить корректную матрицу вида. Если брать не gltf, то в качестве импортируемых данных будут данные перспективы и мировые координаты позиция и вращение. У меня было несколько десятков попыток, но в каждой из них всё что я вижу - это чёрный экран. При этом если поставить lookAt матрицу, где eye в `{0.0f, 0.0f, z}`, то я вижу объект, хотя по мировому расположению не должен. Но я понимаю что сам по себе OpenGL не знает ни что такое мировые координаты, ни что такое камера. Но как научить не знаю. При этом я даже пробовал импортировать сцену во всякие Web редакторы. Там всё ОК. Значит я что-то делаю не так. При этом я проверял и позиция и углы приходят верно. Если я открою ту же сцену в 3d редакторе и задам камеру в позиции и с углами которые я получил (ниже в коде переменная `euler`) всё будет ОК.

```cpp
    aiVector3D d;
    aiQuaternion k;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < scene->mNumAnimations; i++)
    {
        d = scene->mAnimations[i]->mChannels[0]->mPositionKeys[0].mValue;
        k = scene->mAnimations[i]->mChannels[0]->mRotationKeys[0].mValue;
    }

    glm::quat ua{k.w, k.x, k.y, k.z};
    glm::vec3 euler = glm::eulerAngles(ua);
    auto mTrans = glm::translate(glm::mat4{1.0f}, glm::vec3{d.x, d.y, 0.0f});
    glm::mat4 rotM = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 transM;

    rotM = glm::rotate(rotM, euler.x, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    rotM = glm::rotate(rotM, euler.y, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    rotM = glm::rotate(rotM, euler.z, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    ooo.mView = mTrans * rotM;
```

Просьба помочь. Что я делаю не так? И наверное, важно добавить что исходная позиция камеры находится примерно в `{10, 5, 0}`. Т.е. она смотрит в ось X, а не в ось Z.
Сама цена выглядит так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это вид с камеры. Плейн находится в точке 0,0,0

Попробовал упростить.
Gltf файл:

```json
    "cameras":[{
        "type":"perspective",
        "perspective":{
            "znear":0.009999999776482582,
            "zfar":10000000000.0,
            "aspectRatio":1.0,
            "yfov":0.9272952079772949
        }
    }],
    "nodes":[{
        "translation":[10.896925926208496,
        5.699595928192139,
        -3.3627376297927987e-31],
        "name":"cam0",
        "rotation":[0.11757808923721314,
        -0.6972627639770508,
        -0.11757808923721314,
        -0.6972627639770508],
        "scale":[1.0,
        1.0,
        1.0],
        "camera":0
    },
    {
        "translation":[0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0],
        "name":"plane",
        "rotation":[0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0,
        -1.0],
        "scale":[1.0,
        1.0,
        1.0],
        "mesh":0
    }],
```

Это камера и сам меш. Ведь по логике оно  должно работать так:

```cpp
Camera Importer::processCam(aiCamera *cam, const aiScene *scene)
{
    glm::vec3 translation{10.896925926208496f, 5.699595928192139f, -3.3627376297927987e-31f};
    glm::quat rotation{0.11757808923721314f, -0.6972627639770508f, -0.11757808923721314f, -0.6972627639770508};
    glm::vec3 planeTrans{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    glm::quat planeRot{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f};
    Camera ooo{};
    glm::mat4 proj = glm::perspective(0.9272952079772949f, 1.0f, 0.009999999776482582f, 10000000000.0f);
    auto view = glm::translate(glm::mat4{1.0f}, translation) * glm::mat4_cast(rotation);
    auto model = glm::translate(glm::mat4{1.0f}, planeTrans) * glm::mat4_cast(planeRot);
    ooo.mView = proj * view * model;
    return ooo;
}
```

Сейчас mView - это перемножение всех матриц: проекции, вида и самого объекта. Но по прежнему чёрный экран

UPD: Я вообще больше практикую Vulkan. Но тут решил опробовать OpenGL. ВРоде говорят быстрее разработка. Я перенёс код в проект на вулкане. Да, с таким кодом тоже не особо работало. Но быстро получилось всё там. А в OpenGL такое ощщущение что он принудительно смотрит в ось Z.

Код идентичный:

```cpp
glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(-10.8969f, 5.6996f, 0.1f), glm::vec3{0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}, glm::vec3{0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f});
```

OpenGL:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Vulkan:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я даже ставил дебаг и проверял матрицу (proj * view * model). Выходная матрица идентична. Я слышал что в OpenGL ось Y развернута, но я пробовал и отрицательные углы, и отрицательную позицию.

UPD: Я пока ищу подходящую формула для преобразования мирового пространства в координатную систему OpenGL, но возник ещё один вопрос. Это дальность камеры. Я пока в 3d редакторе сделал камеру, разместил её по оси Z и просто перекопировал координаты. В Vulkan-е выглядит ровно также как и в редакторе. А в OpenGL дальность другая. При этом данные как перспективы, так и сами координаты идентичные.

Слева OpenGL. Справа Vulkan
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]